# Can't find odoo-bin.py after installing odoo13 using .deb package

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-13

friends!

I installed Odoo 13 community on Ubuntu 20.04 and now I can't find odoo-bin.py for to activate Odoo Python integrated shell.
For installation I used .deb package.

```
david@david:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/cli$ --shell-interface python
--shell-interface: command not found
david@david:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/cli$ --shell-interface python3
--shell-interface: command not found
david@david:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/cli$
```

How can I setup Odoo shell?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you have followed the documentation properly. `--shell-interface` is not a command as you can see from the error. Please try to understand each step you take.

Comment: I also tried `odoo-bin shell` but did not work.

Comment: I was following documentation during installing Odoo13.